# How do you build a 3 column layout of varying height images for the iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to create a screen that scrolls vertically - like the tableview but I need 3 columns and within those 3 columns I need to add images of varying height - so this will not fit into rows that a tableview can provide.

Should I create 3 tableviews and lay them out side by side - or something else. I think I could build this by simply positioning the images using coordinates but I wanted to benefit from methods that the table view can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the columns to act stuck together, so that they all scroll simultaneously, then I think best approach is to use `UIScrollView` with the images added in the correct placed "by hand."  UITableView and friends is not built to handle non-lined up columns.

**added** If you do use a `UIScrollView`, and you have a large number of images you want to display (that is, the user can scroll for a long time), then it would be wise to recycle your `UIImageView` objects that are scrolled off the screen.  This is what `UITableView` does with `UITableViewCell` objects, and that's why `UITableView` wins.  You can win, too, if you code carefully.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try @tyler. That was exactly why I wanted to use UITableView - in fact I was looking at the Three20 subclass as it's more suited to loading in over the network.  Also - yes I do want to offset columns in exactly that way so good guessing

Answer (score 0):

Three table views would work, but in order to keep things neat and from the same datasource, I would consider using a subclassed UIPickerView and the UIPickerViewDelegate/UIPickerViewDataSource.

Particularly necessary methods:

```
// UIPickerViewDataSource

– numberOfComponentsInPickerView:
– pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:

// UIPickerViewDelegate

– pickerView:rowHeightForComponent:
- pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:
```

Comment: I think he wants offset columns like Pinterest.  You're right, you could use three table views, but they wouldn't naturally scroll together, and I'm guessing it would be hard to achieve that effect with this approach (the scroll-together effect).  You can try to hack it by manually setting the contentOffset, but I suspect it wouldn't look as smooth as the UIScrollView approach.

Answer (score 0):

According to my opinion You should have to take three `UITableView` in xib file and take its IBOutlet then give each `UITableView` an unique tag and then implement UITableView's Delegate methods and in that Methods Check for Tag and then assign values.

Along With this, the other solution, you can also use UIPickerView and then implement UIPickerView's delegate methods also..

Happy Coding !!!